# Lazyloading children from other modules in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm having an issue where child routes are presenting at the app root level.

My app is structured with a root app module that imports a SecureModule and a PublicModule.  The SecureModule then imports a ProviderModule and PracticeModule.  Each module defines it's own routes with .forChild (with the exception being the AppModule which defines forRoot).  For some reason, all default paths (the ones listed with '' as the path) in each module present at the root app module level.

Here is an Augury diagram illustrating the root tree: 
[image: Augury Root Tree]

The SecureComponent is a feature component (no selector) that defines the layout for the secure area and has it's own router-outlet.  As you can see from the root tree, the Practice and Provider module paths layout perfectly under it.  However, the Practice and Provider modules also come straight off the AppComponent as well.

I am lazy loading the child paths via loadChildren and using pathMatch full on my default paths so I'm not sure why they are attaching to the root component.

My secure module routes are defined as such:

```
export const secureRoutes = [
{
    path: 'secure', component: SecureComponent, children: [
        { path: '', redirectTo: 'firstuse', pathMatch: 'full' },
        { path: 'firstuse', component: FirstUseComponent },
        { path: 'practice', loadChildren: './+practice#PracticeModule' },
        { path: 'provider', loadChildren: './+provider#ProviderModule' }
    ]
},
```

];

my practice routes are defined as:

```
export const practiceModuleRoutes = [
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: 'dashboard', component: PracticeDashboardComponent },
{ path: ':id', component: PracticeViewerComponent }
];
```

my app routes are defined as:

```
export const appModuleRoutes: Routes = [
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'public', pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: 'public', component: PublicComponent },
{ path: 'id_token', redirectTo: 'secure' },
{ path: 'logoff', component: LogoffComponent },
{ path: 'Unauthorized', component: UnauthorizedComponent },
{ path: '**',    component: NoContentComponent },
];
```

Does anybody have thoughts on why those Practice and Provider default routes are presenting at the root app component?

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that my AppModule was importing the Secure and Public modules.  When it did that, it seems to have included the routes for those modules at the root level.  When the loadChildren occurred, it also loaded the correct paths for those routes which is why they exist in both places.

To resolve my issue, I removed the importing of the SecureModule and PublicModule from the AppModule.  This cleared the way for the paths to get loaded only as children.